# C++ inherited functions not being found

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

I new in C++ and I have difficulty to understand how to get my function with inheritance.
I have a Class that is link to another with inheritance, everything work except:

## I cannot reach my superclass function.

Here's my class header : Point.h (I don't include the .cpp):

```
#ifndef Point_H
#define Point_H
#include <iostream>
class Point{
  public:
         Point(); 
         void set_values (int , int);
         void set_values (int , int , int );
         void affichervaleurs();
         int getX() const { return x; }
         int getY() const { return y; }
  private:
         int x ;
         int y ;
         int z ;
  };
#endif
```

Now My other class that try to access the function getX from Point.h :
The header : Carre.h

```
#ifndef Carre_H
#define Carre_H
#include "Point.h"

class Carre : public Point{      
  public:
         Carre();
         //Carre(int a , int b);
         //Carre(int a, int b):Point(a,b) {};
         //Carre(int a, int b, int c):Point(a, b, c) {};
         //const Point &pp;
         int Aire (){
         };
         void affichercar(){
                       };

  };
#endif
```

Carre.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Carre.h"
#include "Point.h"

Carre::Carre():Point(){
  };
         //Carre::Carre(int a, int b);
         //const &pp;
         int Aire (){
              return (getX() * getY()); 
         };
         void affichercar(){
         //cout << "Coordonnees X:" << x  << endl;
                       };
```

It says that my GetX() is undeclared in my Carre.cpp .
Like I said I'm new in C++
Does someone know what I'm missing to make that code work. ?

Comment: Use English names (for identifiers, comments, messages, code...) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch They're just names and could be anything. The question's perfectly understood.

Comment: Need full qualifier with in front of int Aire ()

Comment: And btw, styles ... #ifndef CARRE_H also indentation in Carre.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition is missing the class scope, which makes it a free function instead of a member.

It should be

```
int Carre::Aire (){
    return getX() * getY(); 
};
```

Comment: Right, otherwise it's declaring an independent function with no relation to the class.

Answer (score 2):

In the .cpp file for Carre, the functions Aire and affichercar are global. Presumably you intended:

```
int Carre::Aire(){
          return (getX() * getY()); 
     };
```

For example.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring function outside class body requires a class specifier:

```
int Carre::Aire () {
    return (getX() * getY()); 
};

void Carre::affichercar() {
    //...
}
```

Otherwise

```
int Aire () {
    return (getX() * getY()); 
};
```

is just another function in global namespace that can exists simutaneously to `Carre::Aire()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not implementing the `Aire` function as being part of the `Carre` class.

Try changing

```
int Aire (){
```

to

```
int Carre::Aire (){
```

Also, you already have an implementation of the `Aire` method in the header file.  You should either implement the function inline in the header file, or in the .cpp file, but not both.  This also applies to your `affichercar` method.